# What is best practice for modeling a SaaS app with Firebase on a many-to-many relationship

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

I have two collections: an `org` and a `user`. A user can be a regular user of `org A` but can also be an admin of `org B`. So the user collection would look something like this:

```
{
email: "john@example.com",
name: "John Doe",
access: [
    {
        org: "orgA",
        role: "user"
    },
    {
        org: "orgB",
        role: "admin"
    }
]}
```

The problem with keeping everything in the same collection is that I do not like admins of `org A` to update the `access` array and impact `org B`. If I move the `access` array in a sub-collection under the `/user` collection when showing the list of users for each collection, I'd have to make a call for each user to get the access info. Should I save the user IDs in an array in a sub-collection under the `/org` collection?

I guess my goal is to find a best practice solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest database structure I can think of would be:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
   |    |
   |    --- $uid (document)
   |         |
   |         --- email: "john@example.com"
   |         |
   |         --- name: "John Doe"
   |         |
   |         --- userOf (map)
   |         |     |
   |         |     --- orgA: true
   |         |
   |         --- adminOf (map)
   |               |
   |               --- orgB: true
   |
   --- organizations (collection)
        |
        --- $orgA (document)
        |    |
        |    --- users: ["uidOne", "uidTwo"] (array)
        |
        --- $orgB (document)
             |
             --- admins: ["uidThree", "uidFour"] (array)
```

In this way, you can simply query the "users" collection to get regular users of some organization, as well as admin, or even both.

Answer (score 1):

You have two approaches, one is insert a key of access in user, and the same in access. Otherwise you can use a Junction table, with the id of both. There is no exact answer, with the right safety rules and for performance is practically the same. Then decide based on the approach you feel is most appropriate for you design.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on  "insert a key of access in user, and the same in access"? Thanks!

Comment: I find the "junction" (cross/relationship) collection to be the most flexible, thought it does create the requirement of multiple requests